# Mostrar alerta de sucesso com o sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ao gravar o formulário na base de dados pretendo mostrar uma mensagem de sucesso ao utilizador. Estou a tentar usar o `sweetalert2`, mas não está a funcionar. já tenho as bibliotecas:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

No sucesso do ajax tenho desta forma, mas não está a funcionar:

```
success: function(result)
{ 
 $('.form4')[0].reset();
 swal('Boa!', 'Gravado com sucesso!', 'success');
}
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> sweetalert2.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'constructor' of undefined

Função completa:

```
function inserir_registo()
{  
    var dadosajax = {
        'Pedido' : $("#Pedido").val(),
        'Assunto' : $("#Assunto").val(),
        'Descricao' : $("#Descricao").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './requisicaomanutencao12',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
          swal("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        $('.form4')[0].reset();
       swal('Boa!', 'Gravado com sucesso!', 'success');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo. Onde você viu essa função `swal` na documentação? Na página de [utilização](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage) e [exemplo](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) está sendo chamado `Swal.fire({ ... })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À partir da versão `8.0.0`, a função `swal()` passou a ser `Swal.fire()`, conforme você pode ver nesta [documentação oficial](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v8.0.0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você está usando a versão `8.11.8`.